# Can I substitute buttermilk by curdling coconut milk with acid?

Tags: baking, substitutions

I love to bake but can't justify buying buttermilk for the odd time a recipe calls for it.  Instead, I add vinegar to milk to replicate the buttermilk.(it works perfectly).  At the same time, I LOVE to bake with coconut milk, substituting it for milk in the recipe.  My question is, can I add vinegar to coconut milk and get the same results when substituting it for the buttermilk?

Comment: Not directly answering that question: Curdling with acid works on soymilk too, less so on coconut milk.

Comment: You might look for buttermilk powder - it will keep longer, so it makes more sense for occasional uses.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. Cow milk has proteins, which curdle when exposed to acid, thickening the whole thing. Coconut milk is simply a suspension of fat in water, with very few carbohydrates and practically no proteins. You cannot curdle it with acid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,it can! Coconut buttermilk - made with full fat coconut milk and vinegar can be substituted in most recipes for baking. It's a wonderful alternative for those who are dairy intolerant or vegan. It works great in biscuits! Here's a recipe from the internet that I have used with success. https://cooknourishbliss.com/2012/08/08/cream-biscuits/

Comment: Hey user106558, thanks so much for your reply.  Welcome to this site, I hope you enjoy it as much as I do!